# cant connect to MySQL on aws RDS with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to an RDS instance with flask-sqlalchemy. But i cant get it to work. I am getting the error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database 'dbname'")¨
```

My database URI looks like this

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql://username:password@dbname.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/dbname'
```

I have tried using the pymysql plugin, but it didnt make any difference.

I think my security groups are setup correctly.
On the RDS instance it is this

[image: i]

(I dont know if security groups contain any personnel info)

Comment: AWS will create the initial database for you if you specify the database name in the "Additional Configuration" section of the "Create Database" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating the database first:

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy 

mysql_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql://username:password@dbname.xxxxxxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306")

pd.read_sql_query("create database dbname", con=mysql_engine)
```